# ElasticSearch - Use function score query field value factor with match query

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use the example on official documents combined with normal match and boolean queries. How to do that?

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "field_value_factor": {
                "field": "likes",
                "factor": 1.2,
                "modifier": "sqrt",
                "missing": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor

Match query:

```
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "name" : "star wars"
        }
    }
```

Boolean query:

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
    "must": [
        {
        "match": {
            "name": "Star Wars"
        }
        }
    ],
    "should": [
        {
        "term": {
            "name.keyword": {
            "value": "Star Wars"
            }
        }
        }
    ]
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just want to do my normal search but also want them to be listed by "likes" field. More likes = more relevancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this should be doable. If you read further down in the [documentation that you linked to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#_detailed_example), there is an example:

> ```
> GET /_search
> {
>     "query": {
>         "function_score": {
>           "functions": [
>             {
>               "gauss": {
>                 "price": {
>                   "origin": "0",
>                   "scale": "20"
>                 }
>               }
>             },
>             {
>               "gauss": {
>                 "location": {
>                   "origin": "11, 12",
>                   "scale": "2km"
>                 }
>               }
>             }
>           ],
>           "query": {
>             "match": {
>               "properties": "balcony"
>             }
>           },
>           "score_mode": "multiply"
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Modifying that slightly for your use case should look something like this:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "functions": [
            {
              "field_value_factor": {
                "field": "likes",
                "factor": 1.2,
                "modifier": "sqrt",
                "missing": 1
              }
            }
          ],
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "name": "Star Wars"
            }
          },
          "score_mode": "multiply"
        }
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this, just going off of the documentation.

Comment: not working. Getting this error: Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [likes] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead

Comment: What is your `"likes"` field mapping?

Comment: "likes": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }

Comment: Sorry forgot what i write (now deleted that comment. it is nothing like that) It just throws that error on integer type.

Comment: Likes is absolute for me now. The top search results must be though highest likes to the lowest ones. They are the utmost relevancy for me. How can i do that?